# What's wrong with this code to switch vertical tabs?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in VBA, I just followed a tutorial about the code same code but the results is always showing Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" My ask what wrong with this code?

```
Sub SwitchVerticalTabs()
Dim SelCol As Long
Dim FristRow As Long
SelRow = Right(ActiveCell.Row, 1) - 25
With Sheet1
.Range("25:324").EntireRow.Hidden = True
FirstRow = 25 + ((SelRow - 1) * 20)
.Range(FirstRow & ":" & FirstRow + 19).EntireRow.Hidden = False
.Range("B3").Value = SelRow + FirstRow
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your goal? Explain the context. `Selrow` will always be negative and so does `FIrstRow`. This is why you're getting the error. Basically, Rownum cannot be negative or 0.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't selected the ActiveCell:

```
 Range("A1").Select
```

Can you try this:

```
Sub SwitchVerticalTabs()
Dim SelCol As Long
Dim FristRow As Long
Sheets("Sheet1").Select '<-- Set sheet first
Range("A1").Select  '<-- and then select the ActiveCell
SelRow = Right(ActiveCell.Row, 1) - 25
With Sheet1
.Range("25:324").EntireRow.Hidden = True
FirstRow = 25 + ((SelRow - 1) * 20)
.Range(FirstRow & ":" & FirstRow + 19).EntireRow.Hidden = False
.Range("B3").Value = SelRow + FirstRow
End With
End Sub
```

Also the Range is wrong:

```
.Range("25:324")
```

It needs to specify the Column Letters, eg:

```
.Range("A25:Z324")
```

Comment: I tray the code, still error coming

Comment: @Amin Al-Hamoud At the very top of your code module make sure to type `Option Explicit`, then press `Enter`. Correct your misspelled variable in declaration `Dim *FristRow* As Long` because it's not being applied to your actual variable `FirstRow`. `Option Explicit` will help you avoid this type of problem.